# One To Many Relationship in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am having trouble creating and testing a one-to-many relationship between two Sequelize models. A User has many Comments.

Here is my User model. It has one attribute: an email address.

It also has an 'associate' class method that gets called elsewhere in the code. I pass in the database models, and 'associate' creates the relationships between the models.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define('User', 
    { 
        email_address: { type: DataTypes.TEXT }
    },
    { 
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                models.User.hasMany(models.Comment);
                models.Comment.belongsTo(models.User);
            }
        }
    });
    return User;
}
```

Here is my Comment model. Simple enough...

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Comment = sequelize.define('Comment',
    {
       text: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false }
    });
    return Comment;
}
```

Then, elsewhere, I want to seed some data and test out the association. Am I correctly associating the new comment with the new user? Or, is there a better way to grab the user I just created and then associate the new comment with it?

After seeding this data, I want to find the new user, retrieve the new comment from the user, and print out the text in order to test the association.

```
User.create({ email_address: 'helloworld@gmail.com' });
Comment.create({ text: 'Hello World', user_id: 1 });

User
  .findById(1)
  .then(function(user) { 
      console.log(user.getComments())
  });
```

This doesn't work. Specifically, it prints the following:

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 2097152,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _boundTo: Comment }
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "text", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "UserId" FROM "Comments" AS "Comment" WHERE "Comment"."UserId" = 1;
Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: column "UserId" does not exist
at Query.formatError (/Users/sherwoodcallaway/Desktop/onboarding-comments/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:357:14)
at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/sherwoodcallaway/Desktop/onboarding-comments/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:88:19)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Query.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Query.handleError (/Users/sherwoodcallaway/Desktop/onboarding-comments/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:131:8)
at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/sherwoodcallaway/Desktop/onboarding-comments/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:180:26)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/sherwoodcallaway/Desktop/onboarding-comments/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:12)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
```

Any idea what's going wrong here? TYVM <3